# How To Use an iPad as a Graphics Tablet?

Tags: graphics-tablet, ipad

I would like to use my iPad as a graphics tablet to draw stuff on Ubuntu.
Is there any solutions to this? As to see that Ubuntu has built-in Tablet support.

Comment: You can barely mount an apple device to exchange files with it, very much doubt it.

Comment: I think that you cannot.

Comment: However, you can download a remote desktop app for iPad, and draw with it.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely a little too late for you, but there is a solution now: [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus). Screen mirroring, pressure sensitivity and multi touch is supported.

Instructions for installation and running can be found in the readme, make sure to follow through the instructions regarding uniput otherwise things like pressure sensitivity will not work.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of this project.

Comment: Are you associated with that project?

Comment: Yes, I am the creator, should I add a disclaimer?

Comment: Yes. That would be benificial. Also, as of now this answer seems more like a link only answer. It will be nice if you **show** what that does and the installation process. See [How to not be a spammer](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Ubuntu Mate 19.10 + iPad Air 2 13.3.1. I came here looking for a mirror-iPad-on-Linux method, but this is mirror-Linux-on-iPad. That is, weylus mirrors a chosen window from Linux on the iPad, so that when drawing on the iPad, the result appears in the chosen window. I will mention that "palm rejection" does not work (out of the box).

Comment: @JānisLazovskis if you want to mirror your iPad screen to Linux you might be interested in: https://h-m-h.github.io/posts/screencast-ipad-to-linux/

Comment: Is Welus still maintained? It was last updated in 2021 and has 100+ open issues on github

Answer (score 0):

In case if your main goal is to have a bigger screen, depending on your ipad version you should be able to connect an hdmi adapter and connect your ipad to a larger monitor.in case if your main goal is to have bigger screen. But check first if your ipad version is able to work with these adapters before you buy it. There are good applications on ipad for drawing.